# DML and Exception Handling - Oracle

Tags: oracle

As per Steven Feuerstein book
When an exception occurs in a PL/SQL block, the Oracle database does not roll back
any of the changes made by DML statements in that block. You are the manager of the application’s logical transaction, so you decide what kind of behavior should occur.
I give it a try:

```
CREATE TABLE DML_Exception (exception_name VARCHAR2(20));
INSERT INTO DML_exception  VALUES('CASE_NOT_FOUND');
INSERT INTO DML_exception  VALUES('TOO_MANY_ROWS');
```

I got both rows in my table

```
Select * from DML_Exception
```

Now I deleted both rows from the table and raise the exception in PL/SQL block.

```
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM dml_exception;
  raise value_error;
END;
```

But my table still containing the both rows. What I missed?

Comment: Uncommitted transaction?

Comment: What client are you using? Maybe it does rollback after an exception?

Comment: As @Stawros sadid, you forgot the COMMIT

Comment: An excellent question about some fundamental principles of transaction and cursor behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed some other parts of the book. Yes, Steven is true – if an exception occurs in a block, all preceding DML effects remain in place. Yet, there should be other mention in the book that any top-level SQL or PL/SQL statement (i.e., anonymous block as well) execution opens a cursor for that statement and if there's an exception during the cursor's execution, all DML effects done during the cursor's execution are rolled back. Perhaps a simple example will give you the clue...

In your original example, you executed ...

```
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM dml_exception;
    raise value_error;
END;
```

... as the top-level statement. Yes, at the end of the block, though still within, your `delete` effects remained in place. Yet, your block raised an exception which got propagated all the way up to the top-level cursor. Thus, in order to adhere to the principles of [atomicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), Oracle rolled back all pending effects of the opened cursor.

If you call your PL/SQL block from within another top-level PL/SQL block, which handles and does not re-raise the exception raised in the lower-level PL/SQL block, ...

```
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM dml_exception;
        raise value_error;
    END;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN NULL;
END;
```

..., then your `delete` effects shall remain in place. (And since there's no commit in that block, you end up having a transaction in progress.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, my concepts are clear now  :)