# Error catching inside PLSQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

If there is a PLSQL block with 1000 DML statements inside it  and we want to find out which DML statement has thrown error if any then how can we find out that?

Comment: Write an exception block and handle the failures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DML and Exception Handling - Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540754/dml-and-exception-handling-oracle)

Comment: The error message will indicate the line that failed. Please add some more details about the scenario you are facing.

Comment: @XING Not a duplicate - that question is asking why the transaction was rolled back after an exception; not how to find the statement that raised the exception.

Comment: Need to find out which DML statement(it may be update or insert or delete ) has thrown error. Can we rely on line number ?

Comment: @MT0 Question was pretty clear and i got it correctly and replied. Not sure if you are thinking too much to understand OP intention beyond his actual need. See below what OP wanted he himself reiterated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`LOG ERRORS INTO` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BGBDIGAH) in your `INSERT` statement to tell you which data caused the exception:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e3503/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  value INTEGER
        CONSTRAINT MOD5_CHK CHECK ( MOD( value, 5 ) > 0 )
)
/

BEGIN
  DBMS_ERRLOG.CREATE_ERROR_LOG('table_name', 'errlog');
END;
/

DECLARE
  check_violated EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT( check_violated, -2290 );
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
  SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 13
  LOG ERRORS INTO errlog ( 'error' ) REJECT LIMIT 0;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN check_violated THEN
    NULL;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e3503/1/0)**:

No results

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT ORA_ERR_MESG$, ORA_ERR_TAG$, value FROM errlog
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4e3503/1/1)**:

```
|                                                  ORA_ERR_MESG$ | ORA_ERR_TAG$ | VALUE |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|--------------|-------|
| ORA-02290: check constraint (USER_4_4E3503.MOD5_CHK) violated  |        error |     5 |
```

Answer (score -1):

Logging using a SP(preferably using autonomous transaction).

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it is so brief that it does not answer the question. It should possibly be a comment or be expanded to give an example of how to implement the process.

Comment: Don't have enough rep to comment.