# PL/SQL Write a procedure to update a column?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am supposed to update a students grade to 'A' based on procedure

```
ChangeGrade(p_sID, p_classID)
```

If the student is not enrolled in the class (p_classID) then an error message is printed.

Here is the table:

Enrolling

```
sID    classID   Grade
***    *******   *****
104      10440     B
102      10220     C
...      .....     .
```

Am I supposed to do an inner join? Here's what I have:

```
Create or Replace ChangeGrade (
  p_sID enrolling.sID%type
  p_classID enrolling.classID%type )
AS
  p_id_enrolled NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT sID into p_id_enrolled 
  FROM Enrolling
  WHERE sID = p_sID
  AND classID = p_classID

  IF p_sID = p_id_enrolled THEN
    update Enrolling
    set GRADE = 'A'
    dbms_output.put_line('Student grade has been changed.')
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Student record does not exist.')
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: So whats the error. What problem you faced ? `dbms_output.put_line('Student grade has been changed.')` Semicolon is missing at the end. It should be 
`dbms_output.put_line('Student grade has been changed.');`

Comment: Getting an error at line 7: If p_sID = p_id_enrolled THEN it says that the SQL command has not properly ended. At line 2, SELECT sID into p_id_enrolled it says SQL statement ignored.

Comment: Every statement in PL/SQL code has to be followed by `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the problems in your code:

1. This query is meaningless:

   ```
   SELECT sID into p_id_enrolled 
     FROM Enrolling
     WHERE sID = p_sID
     AND classID = p_classID
   ```

   You select `sID` into `p_id_enrolled`, but in `WHERE` clause you filter `sID = p_sID`, so `p_id_enrolled` will always be equal to `p_sID`, and you don't need this select statement at all.
2. This update statement updates the whole table:

   ```
   UPDATE Enrolling
      SET GRADE = 'A';
   ```

   You need to add a filtering clause to update only one row.
3. In a case of student is not enrolled in class, the query returns no rows, and you will get `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception. To process it, you need to catch exception or calculate count of students.

I would recommend to use following:

```
Create or Replace procedure ChangeGrade (
  p_sID enrolling.sID%type,
  p_classID enrolling.classID%type )
AS
  cnt NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) into cnt
    FROM Enrolling
   WHERE sID = p_sID
     AND classID = p_classID;

  IF cnt = 1 THEN
    update Enrolling
       set GRADE = 'A'
     where sID = p_sID
       AND classID = p_classID;
    dbms_output.put_line('Student grade has been changed.');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Student record does not exist.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You say "you don't need this select statement at all" and "you will get `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception" and then you include an SQL statement and don't include the exception without any explanation of why you are not following your own advice.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks, corrected. Actually, it's not me who missed the keyword, I've just copied the code from the question ;) Also, there was a missing comma after the first procedure parameter.

Comment: I think the answer is not completly correct. This code `SELECT count(*) into cnt` gives an ugly error, `ORA-01722: invalid number`, when the student is not enroled in the class.

Answer (score 5):

```
Create or Replace procedure ChangeGrade (
  p_sID enrolling.sID%type
  p_classID enrolling.classID%type )
AS
BEGIN
  update Enrolling
     set GRADE = 'A'
   where sID = p_sID
     AND classID = p_classID;
  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Student grade has been changed.');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Student record does not exist.');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution but a little explanation of why the OP's code won't work would be good.

Comment: @MT0 . Exception block if missing here as well. Please use your DOWNVOTE priv.

Comment: @XING This solution is correct without an exception handling block as it performs the update and checks that the update has either updated a row (by matching the primary key) or has updated zero rows (when the student is not found) - neither possibility will throw a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception as it is not using a `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the fact that the student is not in the class as an exception:

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE ChangeGrade (
  p_sID enrolling.sID%type,
  p_classID enrolling.classID%type,
  p_grade enrolling.grade%type  )
AS
 l_enrolled NUMBER;

BEGIN
  SELECT sID INTO l_enrolled 
  FROM Enrolling
  WHERE sID = p_sID
  AND classID = p_classID;

  IF l_enrolled = p_sID THEN
    update Enrolling set GRADE = p_grade WHERE sID = p_sID and classID = p_classID;
    dbms_output.put_line('Student grade has been changed.');
  END IF;

  EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
    dbms_output.put_line('Student record does not exist for this class');
END;
/
```

I Also added a parameter for the grade because it's logical to pass it as well.

Comment: There is no need in `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` here.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what kind of error is printed out, but it seems like you are missing ';' in the end of some commands (in the if statement and after select into).

Comment: Getting an error at line 7: If p_sID = p_id_enrolled THEN it says that the SQL command has not properly ended. At line 2, SELECT sID into p_id_enrolled it says SQL statement ignored.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, there were several places where `semicolon`(line termiator) was missing in your procedure. Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure ChangeGrade (
  p_sID enrolling.sID%type
  p_classID enrolling.classID%type )
AS
  p_id_enrolled NUMBER;

BEGIN
   SELECT sID
     INTO p_id_enrolled
     FROM Enrolling
    WHERE sID = p_sID AND classID = p_classID;

   IF p_sID = p_id_enrolled
   THEN
      UPDATE Enrolling
         SET GRADE = 'A'
       WHERE sID = p_sID;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Student grade has been changed.');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Student record does not exist.');
   END IF;

 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND Then
dbms_output.put_line('Student record does not exist for this class');

END;
/
```

Comment: You will never get the "Student record does not exist" output as the select query will throw a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception.

Comment: @MT0 Question was not to handle exception rather why Op was getting error. As usual you try to think beyond what OP asked, I have no words for you. Thanks for your downvote. Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664130/error-catching-inside-plsql-block#comment80277180_46664130

Comment: "If the student is not enrolled in the class (p_classID) then an error message is printed." is part of the question - your procedure does not do this. (and you are missing the `PROCEDURE` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a cursor, and then see if the student is enrolled in that course. If he/she is, then update the grade. I think a cursor is more safe then a `SELECT X INTO n`, becasue that does give an ugly error when you try to insert a `NULL`, `SELECT NULL INTO n`, and those errors are generaly hard to find.
For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ChangeGrade (p_sID enrolling.sID%TYPE,
                               p_classID enrolling.classID%TYPE)
AS
              CURSOR cEnrolling IS
                     SELECT     *
                     FROM       Enrolling
                     WHERE      SID = p_sID
                     AND        classID = p_classID;

              rEnrolling cEnrolling%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
        OPEN cEnrolling;
        FETCH cEnrolling INTO rEnrolling;
              IF cEnrolling%FOUND THEN
                      -- Student record found.
                      UPDATE Enrolling
                      SET Grade = 'A'
                      WHERE SID = rEnrolling.sId;

                      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student grade has been changed.');
              ELSE
                      -- Student record not found. 
                      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Student record does not exist.');
              END IF;
        CLOSE cEnrolling;
END;
/
```